# How does mongo executes javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am comparatively new to MongoDB. I understand I can execute JavaScript on mongo-shell. https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/write-scripts-for-the-mongo-shell/

Question1: 
How does Mongo know to execute javascript program?
Does Mongo use nodejs internally?

Question2:
For the javascript file being executed directly on mongo-shell, is there any way to use external libraries like lodash? 
I see declaring `var _ = require('lodash');` does not work on mongo-shell.

Comment: I don't know anything about mongo, but I think they use the `eval()` function, try it, you can evalue strings and I don't think `requirejs` is installed in mongo natively, because that is usually for node.js only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does Mongo use nodejs internally?

MongoDB embeds [Mozilla's JS engine](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/tree/master/src/third_party/mozjs-60).

> I see declaring var _ = require('lodash'); does not work on mongo-shell.

As far as I know MongoDB does not provide a nodejs-compatible runtime.  It [does have a way of loading scripts from the file system](https://github.com/mongodb-labs/drivers-evergreen-tools/blob/master/.evergreen/auth_aws/aws_e2e_ec2.js#L4). So, if you provide the files in the proper format, you could potentially have lodash in your MongoDB shell (assuming lodash does not require any of the functionality that MongoDB JS runtime does not implement).